# Handling Data & Sorting Results in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am having trouble manipulating the data returned from a Python/Kubectl query.

My goal is to get all NAMEs that are great than 30 days old (>30d).

After that, I want to load the NAMEs of these results into an array.

**Python script:**

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["kubectl", "get", "namespaces"])
```

**Data returned in the terminal from Python script:**

```
NAME                      STATUS   AGE
dread-gorge               Active   24d
dread-lagoon              Active   210d
carncier-basin            Active   164d
chantague-shallows        Active   164d
hilraine-loch             Active   311d
stangrave-waters          Active   271d
```

Comment: what's the data type of the returned data?

Comment: it's the result of a Python query that runs a kubectl script on a Linux machine, I should have mentioned. It just prints out the results in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

How about this: `^([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)+) +\w+ +(?:\d{3,}|[3-9]\d)d`

https://regex101.com/r/SOmSm6/1

Answer (score 1):

Let `inp` is your input data (as array).

Prepare regex:
`([-a-z]+)` - NAME
`([A-Za-z]+)` - STATUS
`(\d+)` - AGE (last 'd' will be discarded)

`\s` - sequence of spaces and tabs of any length.

The first value of `match` will be the whole string, so indexing starts with 1 (1 - NAME, 3 - AGE)

```py
result = []
max_days = 30
pattern = re.compile(r'([-a-z]+)\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+(\d+)d')
for line in inp[1:]:
    match = pattern.match(line)
    if int(match[3]) > max_days:
        result.append(match[1])
```

Comment: I get the errror     inp[1:]
TypeError: 'CompletedProcess' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I think you need to do the following to get input: `result = subprocess.run(["kubectl", "get", "namespaces"], capture_output=True, text=True)` , and then get the list of strings: `inp = result.stdout.split('\n')`. I don't have a chance to check it now, but I think it should work.

Comment: tried with the amended input but, still the same result.

Comment: please show the output of subprocess.run